# jQuery to change content in container based on selection from toolbar

Tags: jquery

Here's a screenshot of what I'm working with:

[image]

**What's supposed to happen:** By default, the social feed is set to the Twitter stream. When the user clicks any of the other streams from the toolbar, the content below should switch to the other content. I can't quite figure out how to toggle what is shown.

Here's my jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    // Sets the default stream to Twitter and selects it in the toolar
    $("#feedFilter li").first().addClass("selected");
    $("#socialFeed .twitterFeed").show();

    $("#feedFilter li").click(function() {
        // Clears the white background on the toolbar selection
        $(this).parent().find("li").removeClass("selected");

        // Toggles the white background on the toolbar selection
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");

        // Clears out all socialFeed lists
        $("#socialFeed").fadeOut();

        // Gets the index of the stream selected in the toolbar and shows the stream
        var x = $(this).index();
        switch(x) {
            case 0: $("#socialFeed .twitterFeed").fadeIn(); break;
            case 1: $("#socialFeed .facebookFeed").fadeIn(); break;
            case 2: $("#socialFeed .newsFeed").fadeIn(); break;
            case 3: $("#socialFeed .linkedInFeed").fadeIn(); break;
        }
    });
```

Here's my code so you can see the hierarchy:

```
[...]

<div class="containerSubHeader">
    <ul id="feedFilter">
        <li>Twitter</li>
        <li>Facebook</li>
        <li>Google News</li>
        <li>LinkedIn</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="mainContainer grad-lt-grey">
    <ul id="socialFeed" class="twitterFeed">
        <?php
            [Gets the Twitter content here and puts in <li> items]
        ?>
    </ul>
    <ul id="socialFeed" class="facebookFeed">
        <?php
            [Gets the Facebook content here and puts in <li> items]
        ?>
    </ul>
    <ul id="socialFeed" class="newsFeed">
        <?php
            [Gets the Google News content here and puts in <li> items]
        ?>
    </ul>
    <ul id="socialFeed" class="linkedInFeed">
        <?php
            [Gets the LinkedIn content here and puts in <li> items]
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>

[...]
```

---

This is not working, but I'm not sure what my problem is. Is there a better way to do it instead? I would just use jQuery to append the correct PHP to the unordered list tags, but that'll get messy and this seemed 'easier' (or so I thought).

Any help?

[**Here is the live site so you can see that it loosely works if you switch to Facebook, but fails after that.**](http://jonathonmoore.com/mkt/index2.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your switch as follows

```
// Gets the index of the stream selected in the toolbar and shows the stream
        var x = $(this).index();
        switch(x) {
            case 0: $(".twitterFeed").fadeIn(); break;
            case 1: $(".facebookFeed").fadeIn(); break;
            case 2: $(".newsFeed").fadeIn(); break;
            case 3: $(".linkedInFeed").fadeIn(); break;
        }
```

Selector `$("#socialFeed .twitterFeed")` will search for a class `.twitterFeed` which is a child of #socialFeed id.

Comment: You and Brian both provided working answers, but I'll give you the credit since you answered first. I'll probably go with his solution, however, just to avoid any future issues with duplicate IDs.

Comment: Yea.. correct. I didn't notice the duplicate IDs.. It is always better to avoid duplicate IDs especially when you use jQuery.. +1 for @Brian Glaz

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you have duplicate ID values for your `UL` tags. On a given HTML page, ID's should be unique.

if you drop the ID attribute from your `ul`'s and edit your javascript it should work. I am remvoing the ID socialfeed and adding it as a class here:

```
   <ul class="socialFeed twitterFeed">
        <?php
            [Gets the Twitter content here and puts in <li> items]
        ?>
    </ul>
    <ul class="socialFeed facebookFeed">
        <?php
            [Gets the Facebook content here and puts in <li> items]
        ?>
    </ul>
    <ul class="socialFeed newsFeed">
        <?php
            [Gets the Google News content here and puts in <li> items]
        ?>
    </ul>
    <ul class="socialFeed linkedInFeed">
        <?php
            [Gets the LinkedIn content here and puts in <li> items]
        ?>
    </ul>
```

In the jquery i changed selectors to use class instead of id.

```
$(function() {
    // Sets the default stream to Twitter and selects it in the toolar
    $("#feedFilter li").first().addClass("selected");
    $(".socialFeed.twitterFeed").show();

    $("#feedFilter li").click(function() {
        // Clears the white background on the toolbar selection
        $(this).parent().find("li").removeClass("selected");

        // Toggles the white background on the toolbar selection
        $(this).toggleClass("selected");

        // Clears out all socialFeed lists
        $(".socialFeed").fadeOut();

        // Gets the index of the stream selected in the toolbar and shows the stream
        var x = $(this).index();
        switch(x) {
            case 0: $(".socialFeed.twitterFeed").fadeIn(); break;
            case 1: $(".socialFeed.facebookFeed").fadeIn(); break;
            case 2: $(".socialFeed.newsFeed").fadeIn(); break;
            case 3: $(".socialFeed.linkedInFeed").fadeIn(); break;
        }
    });
```